# trying to implement one to many relation on Sonata/AdminBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new in symfony sonata/adminbundle I am trying to use a complected relationship between two tables order and   product(one to many)  order can be associated with multiple products

product table:
id
name
description
type
quantity

order table:
id 
date
I dont have permission to add pictures here yet, so link to picture is bellow 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx3ws.png

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at "SONATA_TYPE_COLLECTION" section here https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html

Comment: thanks debugall, I managed to display products list (line order) on create order page using this " ->add('OrderItems', 'sonata_type_collection', array('required' => true,
          'by_reference' => false,
        ),
          array('edit' => 'inline',
            'targetEntity' => 'test\testBundle\Entity\OrderItem',
            'inline' => 'table',))"

Answer (score 1):

So, you are not very curious, search a little before ask here, and after, you will win reputation and be able to share pictures on stackoverflow.

Here, a great example provided by Symfony2 official documentation, for build relation One Category To Many Products (Same as your, One Order To Many Products) :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations

You just have to follow the example, replace Category by Order in entities mapping, generate CRUD write actions, and it works.